# VBA MS Access Compare values in a column to a value using Instr

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database which contains a main table and a reference table. I'm trying to change a column in the table based on if it contains values in an array (pulled from the reference table) so the logic is something like this

- Compare the value of the array to see if its contained within a column of the main table
- If it is contained in the main table column change the group column to the value in the array

I have the code below which simply compares the value in the array against the table and prints the value. Im getting the error "Type mismatch". Does anyone know how i can compare the records?

```
    Set rstTableName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MAIN_TABLE")

    For Each vItem In MyArray

        Do While Not rstTableName.EOF
            If InStr(1, [rstTableName!NAME], vItem) Then
                Debug.Print (rstTableName!NAME)
            End If
            rstTableName.MoveNext
        Loop
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with just an update query.

For example:
`Main_Table` contains these fields - `ID` (AutoNum) and `FieldToChange` (Text)
`ReferenceTable` contains these fields - `ID` (AutoNum), `ALookUpValue` (Text), `ChangeTo` (Text)

If the value held in `ALookUpValue` appears anywhere in `FieldToChange` then replace the field value with whatevers in `ChangeTo`.

So, if `FieldToChange` contains ABCDEFG, `ALookUpValue` contains A and `ChangeTo` contains 'blah blah' then ABCDEFG will update to say 'blah blah'

```
UPDATE MainTable INNER JOIN ReferenceTable ON MainTable.FieldToChange LIKE '*' & ReferenceTable.ALookUpValue & '*'
SET MainTable.FieldToChange = ReferenceTable.ChangeTo
```

Hope that's understandable - end of the day. :)

**Edit - test on a copy of your database - it will update values!**

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. [Instr()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b) returns a number (specifically variant type of Long) which is the first position of the lookup value. You have it compared to a boolean (T/F). But in VBA this is still legal as False is zero value and True non-zero value. However, it is advised never to rely on the equivalent numeric values of these [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0y616xy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
2. Brackets should not be wrapped around your entire recordset item but only around the field name:
3. Check the array item types. How it is declared and populated may invoke a `Type Mismatch` error. You do not include how array, `MyArray` is initialized and defined. For your needs, you need either `String` or `Variant` type array.

Try the following adjustment:

```
Set rstTableName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MAIN_TABLE")

For Each vItem In MyArray

    Do While Not rstTableName.EOF
        If InStr(1, rstTableName![NAME], vItem) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print (rstTableName![NAME])
        End If
        rstTableName.MoveNext
    Loop

Next vItem
```

Alternatively, use the [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator

```
Set rstTableName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MAIN_TABLE")

For Each vItem In MyArray

    Do While Not rstTableName.EOF
        If rstTableName![NAME] Like "*" & vItem & "*" Then
            Debug.Print (rstTableName![NAME])
        End If
        rstTableName.MoveNext
    Loop

Next vItem
```